# How to write visitor classes for collections?

Tags: antlr4

The example LabeledExpr.g4 in the book describes how to use the visitor classes for singletons. But if I want to visit a class which is a collection, how do I do it? e.g. for the grammar:

```
prog:   stat+ ;
stat:   expr NEWLINE   # printExpr
        ;
```

The visitor function for print is shown as:

```
public Integer visitPrintExpr(LabeledExprParser.PrintExprContext ctx) {
    Integer value = visit(ctx.expr()); // evaluate the expr child
    System.out.println(value);         // print the result
    return 0;                          // return dummy value
}
```

What would be the corresponding visitor function for 'stat+', so that I can traverse the list of 'stat'?

The reason I am looking for this is, I may want to parse and store the entire object model in memory first, and then do several passes of visiting and analysis on it (instead of on-the-fly evaluating/printing as the book example shows).

A related question is, if I create some data structures within the grammar file (as shown in ActionExpr.g4 in the book), how do I access these data structures in the visitor functions? e.g. how can the Expr class created below be accessed in the visitor function?

```
stat  [Expr e]
      :   expr NEWLINE   # printExpr
           {$e = new Expr($expr);}
      ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete collection is returned by the generated `ProgContext.stat()` method. You can access it from within the `visitProg` method of the visitor.

Comment: Thanks. But now I have a different problem - the code works in eclipse, but not in command line (neither windows, nor unix). I have posted a different question for that because it looks like a bug of some sort - 20138858.